# ESLINT: Prevent the use of double exclamation (!!)

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

What is the rule and configuration required to stop eslint (when using `eslint --fix`) from changing:

```
return regex.test(foo) ? true : false
```

into this:

```
return !!regex.test(foo)
```

While I understand what this rule is doing, I don't like it. I thought it might be one of these -- however, it's either neither, or I just fail to understand how to configure them correctly.

- [no-implicit-coercion](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-coercion)
- [no-extra-boolean-cast](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-extra-boolean-cast)

```js
// eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  rules: {
    'no-implicit-coercion': [2, { string: false, boolean: false, number: false }],
    'no-extra-boolean-cast': [2, { enforceForLogicalOperands: true }],
  }
}
```

Comment: why even have the ternary in the first place? `.test` returns a boolean

Comment: Perhaps [no-uneeded-ternary](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary)? (One could certainly make a case for this ternary being superfluous...)

Comment: Why don't you run eslint without fix and see what rule triggers for the specific case?

Comment: [DanielA.White] Poor example on my behalf, but ultimately effective at demonstrating what I'm referring to. [AlexanderNied] That's the ticket mate. Cheers. [ASDFGerte] In retrospect, you're absolutely right. I have no idea why I didn't think to do that lol.

Comment: I couldn't get eslint to convert the readable `return a ? true : false` to `return !!a`. It did convert it to `return Boolean(a)`. Using `!!` is discouraged in eslint (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-implicit-coercion) and I don't understand why the "fix" uses discouraged practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [no-unneeded-ternary](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unneeded-ternary) is converting this, as it is ultimately superfluous and can be written more cleanly and succinctly without a ternary.  That said, as [Salman A points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70105139/eslint-prevent-the-use-of-double-exclamation?noredirect=1#comment-123931288_70105139), it is somewhat curious that the fix itself is leveraging what is considered a bad practice of the `!!` Boolean casting.